# Identify vtables while disassembling

Tags: c++, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Are there any good strategies for identifying vtables while disassembling?  Right now, I'm using brute force by scanning the .rdata section looking at byte combinations that point back to the code section.  I do further checks then to see if it destination looks like a function prolog but overall this approach just doesn't seem efficient and prone to lots of false positives.

I suppose the other way would be to do the reverse by looking for a vtable reference in the code section and then start the parsing at where it points in .rdata but again, it has issues.

So just curious if there's a more efficient way than a brute force check.

Comment: To answer this question one would need to be specific about the compiler that is used here. Afaik the location of the vtable is not defined by the c++ standard and is compiler-implementation dependent.

Comment: I realize it is compiler dependent but I'm looking for a generic solution.  Although I suppose multiple compiler specific solutions could also be developed with a generic fallback if the compiler is not supported.

Comment: Are your binaries stripped?  There may be symbols (maybe non-global) for the vtables for different types.  Do you maybe have a symbol for functions that construct objects of the types you want?  (They would have need to store the a pointer to the vtable into memory).  But it's probably hard to automate that last part.